# Kohana 3.3 multi language

Tags: kohana, multilingual

Following the tutorial @ http://kerkness.ca/kowiki/doku.php?id=example_of_a_multi-language_website

I need to override the Request class, but there is no instance method.

What do i need to change to get it working in kohana v3.3 ?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of Request::instance() was replaced with Request::$current since Kohana 3.2, so you should write this in top of your Request class:

```
 class Request extends Kohana_Request {

  public static function current( & $uri = TRUE)
  {
     ...
```